# Importing modules within directories in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to break my code into different files. I have a file, lets name common_functions.py, a.py and b.py. I am using functions from common_fucntions.py in a.py and b.py. a.py and b.py have class definition that I am using inside my main.py that located at parent directory. So the structure is

```
+--_dir
|  +-- a.py
|  +-- b.py
|  +-- comon_functions.py
+-- main.py
```

I did "import common_functions" inside a.py and b.py it works fine but the main throws ModuleNotFoundError when I import dir.a and dir.b inside main.py. If I add dir.common_functions in a.py and b.py, the main works fine but a.py and b.py throw the same error.

How can I structure my project to avoid this, or how can I import the files correctly.

Comment: Is the directory called `_dir`? So you'd need `import _dir.a` and `import _dir.b` in `main.py`?

Comment: use local imports inside `a.py` and `b.py`: `from .common_functions import foo` (note the dot)

Comment: I did import _dir.a and _dir.b inside main. But in the file a.py and b.py, I have import common_functions, for which I get error in main.py

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding line "import .common_functions" in a.py and b.py and adding "import _dir.a" and "import _dir.a" in main.py. Thanks guys.